# Why didn't the channel take the value of the last declaration?

Tags: go

I am trying to learn about channels. In this code, I have declared values from 1 to 10. The final declaration's value is 10, but when I print it, it always returns the value from the two declarations before(8). If someone can explain, I would be very pleased.

```
func main() {
    channel := make(chan int, 3)
    isOver := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for val := range channel {
            fmt.Println(val)
        }
        isOver <- true
    }()

    channel <- 1
    channel <- 2
    channel <- 3
    channel <- 4
    channel <- 5
    channel <- 6
    channel <- 7
    channel <- 8
    channel <- 9
    channel <- 10
    close(channel)

    fmt.Println("Channel Value is: ", <-channel)

    <-isOver

}
```

[image: output of code]

When I changed the declaration to 8, it returned the value from the two declarations before that, which is 6.

Comment: It's a race condition, program output will vary if you try to run it multiple times.

Comment: Actually, it does not change. Always gives same output. But I thinks is related to buffer channel. When i changed buffer size, Channel values changed

Comment: I am not sure, how you are getting same value each time. But it's definitely a race condition because both goroutines (main and other that reading channel value) are trying to access channel value. Output will differ each time. Try running multiple times.

Comment: By the time the Println function is called the anonymous goroutine will have received any number of values from the channel. Here it happens to be seven, so the main goroutine receives the eighth (note that the anonymous goroutine does not receive 8. It receives 7, then 9).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you set 3 buffer size for channel!

Note: your example have deferent output in deferent OS ( for example I get `Channel Value is: 0`)

set time.Sleep in your code for see what happen. In your code:

```golang
func main() {
    channel := make(chan int)
    isOver := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for val := range channel {
            fmt.Println(val)
            // sleep 1 second
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
        isOver <- true
    }()

    channel <- 1
    channel <- 2
    channel <- 3
    channel <- 4
    channel <- 5
    channel <- 6
    channel <- 7
    channel <- 8
    channel <- 9
    channel <- 10
    close(channel)

    fmt.Println("Channel Value is: ", <-channel)
    <-isOver
}
```

output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
Channel Value is:  8
9
10
```

Note: better way for understand what happen in your code, trace your code step by step.

What happened ?
See this trace:

```
1 // print 1 and sleep 1s
2,3,4 // stop for get values

3,4 // print 2 and sleep 1
3,4,5 // stop for get value

4,5 // print 3 and sleep 1
4,5,6 // stop for get value

5,6 // print 4 and sleep 1
5,6,7 // stop for get value

6,7 // print 5 and sleep 1
6,7,8 // stop for get value

7,8 // print 6 and sleep 1
7,8,9 // stop for get value

8,9 // print 7 and sleep 1
8,9,10 // stop for get value
// close channel
// in this line get value : fmt.Println("Channel Value is: ", <-channel)

9,10 // before get value
10 // get 9 and sleep 1
// get 10 and sleep 1

// isdone send signal true
```

In trace code when channel got tree value 8,9,10 ,channel closed, in this step 2 thing happened:

1 - if goroutine get fast all value (Channel Value is: 0)
2 - if goroutine was busy (Channel Value is: 7 or 8 or 9 or 10)

for more info see this question: [when to use a buffered channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15113410/when-to-use-a-buffered-channel)
and see this website for better understand : [Link](https://www.golinuxcloud.com/golang-buffered-channel/)